# Nginx Reverse Proxy Configuration with Gitlab Docker Container

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hey there fellow developers,

I'm currently facing an issue with my server setup involving multiple Docker services running behind an Nginx reverse proxy. I've successfully configured my domain (via Linode) and subdomains to route traffic through the proxy to various Docker containers. For instance, I can access my Nextcloud instance at `cloud.domainname.com`, which forwards requests to my Nextcloud container running on port 8080.

Recently, I've been trying to set up GitLab using a similar Docker configuration for my reverse proxy. I've exposed ports 82, 444, and 23 for GitLab, as ports 81, 443, and 22 are already occupied by other services.

My GitLab setup isn't working as expected, and I'm currently encountering a 502 Bad Gateway error when attempting to access it via `gitlab.domainname.com`, which is mapped to my GitLab container on port 82. I've tried setting the GitLab hostname and environment variables, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Here's a snippet of my Docker Compose configuration for GitLab:

```yaml
hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
environment:
  GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
    external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
    # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
ports:
  - 82:80
  - 444:443
  - 23:22
```

I've already gone through the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Checked Docker container logs for any error messages.
2. Verified my Nginx reverse proxy configuration.
3. Ensured the firewall is not blocking port 82.
4. Double-checked the GitLab container configuration, including the `external_url`.
5. Confirmed DNS settings to point `gitlab.domainname.com` to the correct server IP.
6. Validated SSL/TLS certificate configuration.
7. Restarted both the GitLab container and Nginx after making changes.

Despite these efforts, I'm still stuck with the 502 error. Could someone kindly assist me in identifying what might be causing this issue or offer suggestions on how to debug and resolve it?

Your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

---